# While first index is an array?

Tags: javascript

*I can tell I'm falling through my while loop, from frame 3 to 4.*

**Am I not checking the condition in my while loop correctly?**

```
function steamrollArray(arr) {
  var R2 = [];
  while (arr[0].isArray) {
    console.log(arr[0]);
    R2.push(arr[0]);
    return R2;
  }
  return R2;
}

steamrollArray([[["a"]], [["b"]]]); // should return ["a", "b"].
steamrollArray([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]); // should return [1, 2, 3, 4].
steamrollArray([1, [], [3, [[4]]]]); // should return [1, 3, 4].
steamrollArray([1, {}, [3, [[4]]]]); // should return [1, {}, 3, 4].
```

[Step 3 to 4](http://www.pythontutor.com/javascript.html#mode=display)

Comment: Your misuse of `isArray` is the first of several problems in this code -- for one, your code immediately returns after pushing exactly one item to `R2`; for another, the code doesn't dig into the contents of `arr[0]` so you know for sure that what gets pushed into `R2` must be an array, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to have some logic bugs (besides the syntactic error in not using `Array.isArray`). To achieve the desired result, you can use recursion like below:

```js
function steamrollArray(arr) {
  var R2 = [];

  for (var element of arr) {
    var nextElements = []; 

    while (Array.isArray(element)) {
      nextElements = element.slice(1);
      element = element[0];
    }

    if (!element) continue;

    R2.push(element);
    var rolledNextElements = steamrollArray(nextElements);
    R2 = R2.concat(rolledNextElements);
  }

  return R2;
}

console.log(steamrollArray([[["a"]], [["b"]]]));
console.log(steamrollArray([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]));
console.log(steamrollArray([1, [], [3, [[4]]]]));
console.log(steamrollArray([1, {}, [3, [[4]]]]));
```

Answer (score 2):

`isArray` is a method of Array - [Array.isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

```
function steamrollArray(arr) {
  var R2 = [];
  while (Array.isArray(arr[0])) {
    console.log(arr[0]);
    R2.push(arr[0]);
    return R2;
  }
  return R2;
}
```

Comment: It's `Array.isArray` not `Array.prototype.isArray` -- therefore, also, `Array.isArray(arr[0])` not `arr[0].isArray()`.

Answer (score 2):

you are using isArray wrong. **It is a method, that takes an input** and checks if it is an array.

```
function steamrollArray(arr) {
  var R2 = [];

  while (Array.isArray(arr[0])) {
    console.log(arr[0]);
    R2.push(arr[0]);
    return R2;
  }
  return R2;
}
```